# Server at (localhost:27017) reports wire version (0), but this version of the Ruby driver requires at least (2).)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

Mongo::Error::UnsupportedFeatures (Server at (localhost:27017) reports wire version (0), but this version of the Ruby driver requires at least (2).)

I am trying to use mongodb in rails application but the above error is getting while trying to create the records via rails console